# Computer restarts over and over after upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 14.10 on dualboot windows/ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, 14.10

I had a dualboot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 (Windows 8 before upgrade).
I decided to upgrade my Ubuntu to 15.04, so I needed to Ubuntu 14.10 and after to Ubuntu 15.04. But after I've upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 I ran into a problem. I can't start a computer it restarts over and over, so I booted into live usb and ran a boot-repair( pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12070000/ ). Then I tried to ran an update-grub but there is an error "error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'", so I googled and mounted an Ubuntu partition and ran a update-grub after chroot there. I also tried to grub-install, but I still can't boot with the same issue. I have a netbook lenovo ideapad s205. I know that there is someone who already asked that question but I don't understand him and he has no dualboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could read from your [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12070000/) it appears your Windows got hibernated at some point:

```
534: Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
```

and consequently os.prober could not detect your Windows installation (line 564).

```
564: 1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 0 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.
```

So in order to quickly get a running system back you should repair Windows using Windows tools, and then perform a clean re-install of Ubunutu 15.04 (upgrade path from 14.10 does no longer work as 14.10 reached end of life).

Data from your HOME directory should stay untouched if you do not fromat your Ubuntu partition. Otherwise you can always restore all of your data from your recent backup.

In case you had no backups, or Windows tools fail to recover Windows you will have more serious issues. It then would be vital to **stop using that drive** and perform a [data recovery of your important files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu/286206#286206).

Only after you had recovered your data you would then re-install Windows, and after that Ubuntu.

It may be possible to try to repair your Ubuntu but in the long run it will take much more time than just re-installing and restoring your HOME and your applications.

Comment: What are the "Windows tools"?

Comment: That's tools to repair Windows - I know much about Ubuntu but I unfortunately have no ideas how this is being done nowadays in Windows 10.

Comment: Is it a recovery usb?

Comment: @MichaelVietluzhskih: I really have not the slightest idea on the Windows 10 side. I only know that you may not  be able to do this from Ubuntu. You have to get to where you can boot Windows to shut it down without hibernation.

Comment: I restored a mbr in boot repair and  booted to windows

Comment: That's good news... :) Time for backups if not yet down. Then you should shut down Windows **without hibernation/fast boot**  to then install Ubuntu 15.04 alongside. If it does not offer an "upgrade" option then you should "Do something else" to **avoid formatting of the partition that holds your HOME** (untick format). Also take care to not partition/format your Windows partition. If there were important data without a backup available on the Linux partition you may want to copy them to a safe place from the live CD, provided the partition is readable.